# How to disable hiding of a LayoutAnchorable when using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I'm trying to use AvalonDock with MVVM and disabling the hide feature of a `LayoutAnchorable`. Without MVVM, I can do something like:

```
<xcad:LayoutAnchorable CanHide="False">
  <TextBox>Some Content</TextBox>
</xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
```

The `CanHide="False"` disables hiding.

How can I access the `CanHide` property using MVVM or disable hiding in another way?

I have:

```
<xcad:DockingManager AnchorablesSource="{Binding UserPanelList}">
  <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="xcad:LayoutItem">
      <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
      <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
    </Style>
  </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

  <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Control}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>

  <xcad:LayoutRoot>
    <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
      </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
    </xcad:LayoutPanel>
  </xcad:LayoutRoot>
</xcad:DockingManager>
```

And a completely trivial model class:

```
public class UserPanel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string ContentId { get; set; }
  public bool CanHide { get; set; }         // ??
  // (NotifyPropertyChanged not implemented for these properties here
  // for the sake of brevity. Basically works without.)

  public UserControl Control
  {
    get => _userInterface;
    set
    {
      if (value != _userInterface)
      {
        _userInterface = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
  UserControl _userInterface;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

The view classes are created from the contents of the bound `UserPanelList`.

However, the `LayoutItem` class does not contain a `CanHide` property, i.e. I cannot use a `<Setter>` afaik. What can I do instead?

Comment: Just by <xcad:LayoutAnchorable CanHide="{Binding Path=CanHide">. Just apply the INotifyPropertyChanged on CanHide boolean like you have done on Control UserControl

Comment: @NawedNabiZada There is no `<xcad:LayoutAnchorable ...>`. The `LayoutAnchorables` are created by AvalonDock from the contents of `UserPanelList` bound via `AnchorablesSource="{Binding UserPanelList}"`. That's why I'm using the `<Setter>`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `LayoutAnchorableItem` that derives from `LayoutItem` is used for `LayoutAnchorable`s (see [e.g. here](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DockingManager~GetLayoutItemFromModel.html)). It has a dependency property `CanHide` that works as expected.

On can set the style for `LayoutAnchorableItem` either by

```
<Style TargetType="xcad:LayoutAnchorableItem">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Setter Property="CanHide" Value="{Binding Model.CanHide}" />
```

or, more flexible, by

```
<Style TargetType="xcad:LayoutItem">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Setter Property="xcad:LayoutAnchorableItem.CanHide" Value="{Binding Model.CanHide}" />
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to disable "autohide" as well? Hide only gets rid of the "x" and leaves the "pin symbol"

Comment: @CM0491 I didn’t have a look at disabling autohide. There is a `LayoutAnchorable.CanAutoHide`, but there seems to be no `CanAutoHide` property in `LayoutItem` or derived classes -- at the moment, I have no idea how to do it.